# How to install jmol?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm a student of chemistry and I'd like a piece of software to visualise molecules. I've heard of 'jmol', but I can't  get it installed.

I've downloaded `Jmol-12.1.16-full.tar.gz`, what do I need to do with it?

Thank you,

Philippe

Comment: You can just extract the files and run Jmol.jar

Answer (score 3):

Jmol requires Java 1.4+, so make sure you have an Java Runtime.

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Now we need to extract the Jmol archive you downloaded.

The instructions are, (go to the folder you downloaded):

```
tar -xvzf Jmol-12.1.16-full.tar.gz
cd jmol-12.1.16/
chmod +x
./jmol.sh
```

To make it easier (make a shortcut) and put the location of the `jmol.sh` 
 file.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Jmol's wiki,
http://wiki.jmol.org
there is a section entitled "Installing Jmol" with instructions.